# What is the mathematical equivalent of rotate left?

Tags: algorithm, assembly, rotation

I am trying to decipher some assembly code that involves multiple left rotations on an 8-bit binary number.

For reference, the code is:

```
lab:    rol    dl,1
        rol    dl,1
        dec    ecx
        jnz    lab
```

The `dec` and `jnz` isn't an issue, but is there to show that the 2 `rol`s are executed several times.

What I am trying to do is figure out a mathematical equivalent of this code, such as a formula. I'm certainly not looking for a complete formula to tell me the whole code, but I would like to know if there is a formula that gives the equivalent (in denary) of a single left rotation.

I've tried figuring this out with a couple of different numbers, but cannot see a link between the two results. For example: if the start number is 115 it comes out as 220, but if the start number is 99 it comes out as 216.

Comment: I can't tell how you get 216 for 99. And by 'denary' do you mean 'decimal' perhaps?

Comment: @Karl Knechtel: I can't tell either. But that is what happens, for some reason. Hopefully I can figure it out now I know the equivalent of a rotate left.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Given your sample results, I assume we are treating the 8-bit quantity as unsigned.

The 7 low-order bits are shifted left, multiplying that part of the number by 2; and the high-order bit is swapped around to the beginning.

Thus, `(x % 128) * 2 + (x / 128)`, using the usual integer div/mod operators.

Comment: i don't know what's the point? rotate is simpler and more efficient

Comment: @kvphxga: I'm not looking to simplify the code or make it more efficient, rather, I'm trying to understand what it's doing. The formula helps me do that.

Comment: Equivalently (and more likely to be the original source), `(x << 1) | (x >> 7)` assuming 8-bit operands.

Answer (score -3):

Shifting a byte containing number X by one bit (position) left is equal to multiplying the number X by 2:

x << 1  <==>  x = x * 2

Comment: But shifting isn't the same as rotation, which is what my code is doing.